# plotting an array on F#, how to index axis by year

Tags: f#

I would like to create create a graph of an array on F sharp as follows:

```
let compperformance= Array.zip firstarray secondarray |> Array.map (fun (a,b) 
-> (b-a)) 
Chart.Line(compperformance, Title="dy").WithXAxis(Title="year", Min=1.0, Max=39.0)
                                       .WithYAxis(Title="Cumulative SSE difference")
```

How can I change the x-axis to year (min=1960.0 to max=2000.0)? When I define min and max as such, the graph disappears. Let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a sequence of key value pairs to `Chart.Line`:

```
let compperformance= 
  Array.zip firstarray secondarray |> Array.map (fun (a,b) -> (b-a)) 
let dataWithYears = 
  Array.zip [| 1960 .. 2000 |] compperformance

Chart.Line(dataWithYears, Title="dy")
     .WithXAxis(Title="year", Min=1.0, Max=39.0)
     .WithYAxis(Title="Cumulative SSE difference")
```

This assumes that there is exactly 41 values in `compperformance`, which might not quite work - you may need to do this a bit differently - but it shows the idea - just produce an array containing `year, value` tuples.